# scoped class can't use private member

Tags: c++

I have a boolean which I need to be true only if the function called and false if the function returned. I'm trying a scoped class it's destructor called if the scope ends and it'll try to set it false.

here is my simplified code.

```cpp
class MyClass {
private: bool in_func = false;
public:
    void func() {
        in_func = true;
        // when scope ends I need to set in_func = false
        class ScopeDistruct {
            bool* in_func_ptr = nullptr;
            ScopeDistruct(bool* p) { in_func_ptr = p; }
            ~ScopeDistruct() { *in_func_ptr = false; }
        };
        ScopeDistruct scope_distruct(&in_func);

        /*
            Lots of code.
        */
    }
};
```

but this cause an error `error C2248 : 'MyClass::func::ScopeDistruct::ScopeDistruct' : cannot access private member declared in class 'MyClass::func::ScopeDistruct'` when compiling. what's wrong with my code how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `ScopeDistruct` is declared with keyword `class` and there are no accessibility specifier in the class, so their members including the constructor are private to the class.

You should add `public` to make the constructor public.

```
class ScopeDistruct {
    bool* in_func_ptr = nullptr;
public: // add this
    ScopeDistruct(bool* p) { in_func_ptr = p; }
    ~ScopeDistruct() { *in_func_ptr = false; }
};
```